# How do I invoke a SAM Lambda function locally with X-Ray statements?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-xray

I'm receiving the following error when invoking an AWS SAM Lambda function locally:

`Missing AWS Lambda trace data for X-Ray. Ensure Active Tracing is enabled and no subsegments are created outside the function handler.`

Below you can see my function:

```js
/** Bootstrap */
require('dotenv').config()
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk')

/** Libraries*/
const se                = require('serialize-error')

/** Internal */
const logger            = require('./src/utils/logger')
const ExecuteService    = require('./src/service')

/**
 *
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {    
    const xraySegement = AWSXRay.getSegment()
    
    const message = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body) : event

    try {
        await ExecuteService(message)
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error({
            error: se(err)
        })

        return err
    }
}
```

In addition, I have Tracing set to Active in my template.yml.

What part of the documentation am I clearly misreading, missing, or reading over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now you can't invoke a SAM lambda locally with X-ray because it is not supported yet.

See

- [[Feature Request] Add support for X-Ray on SAM Local
  #217](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/217)
- [aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator#level-of-support](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator#level-of-support)

> The component does not support X-ray and other Lambda integrations locally.

---

If you don't care about X-ray and just want your code to work you can check the env variable `AWS_SAM_LOCAL` to prevent X-ray usage:

```js
let AWSXRay
if (!process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
    AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk')
}

// ...
if (!process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
    const xraySegement = AWSXRay.getSegment()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll need to think of a clever design pattern to hide some of this pollution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `SAM CLI, version 1.36.0`
I noticed importing `aws-xray-sdk` does not create this issue but invoking the functions do.

To not have a million if statements I created a middle man service that imports `aws-xray-sdk` then exports noops if the env var `process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mickael's answer, another way (avoiding if statements around the import and all XRay uses) would be to set XRay's logger to "do nothing" for each log level:

```js
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
const AWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(require('aws-sdk'));

// ignoring AWS X-Ray errors when running locally
if (process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL) {
    AWSXRay.setLogger({
        error: () => {},
        info: () => {},
        warn: () => {},
        debug: () => {},
    })
}
```